# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser - exact only certain info from a div

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I am using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser and only want to extract the address info "1220 28th Ave., San Francisco, CA 94122".  Is it possible to do so?

```
    <address>
        Phone：<strong>(585) 383-8643</strong><br />
        Address： 1220 28th Ave., 
        San Francisco, CA 94122<br />
        Hour：MON-FRI(9-6)                                
    </address>
```

I have to code only to extract the "address" tag:

```
$posts = $html->find('div.result');
foreach ($posts as $item) {
    $address = $item->find('address',0)->plaintext;
    echo $address;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser after this step, try the following code.

```
echo explode('<br />',explode('Address： ',$address)[1])[0];
```